# Missing numbers in bookdown pdf output

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

this is my first post here and my first bookdown project.

i have no idea where I should look further.
The problem: in my pdf-output the first level is *not* numbered and all
page numbers are in *roman* numbers. The table of contents looks like this:

[image: TOC of my pdf output]

The corresponding _output.yaml contains:

```
   bookdown::pdf_book:
      includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
    before_body: before_body.tex
    after_body: after_body.tex 
  latex_engine: xelatex
  number_sections: yes
  fig_caption: yes
  citation_package: natbib
  toc_depth: 4
  toc_unnumbered: no 
  keep_tex: yes
```

HTML output is ok and numbered correctly. I use the latest version of
everything under win 10. As this is my first project,
most other files come from bookdown sample book.  Where should I look
and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: You should check your preamble.tex...

Comment: no idea about tex, which setting controls the index numbering and the page numbers?

Comment: I used the one from https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/examples/latex/preamble.tex and had to delete the line "\setmainfont[UprightFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Regular}]{Alegreya}" because the font is not installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint with the preamble.tex, I deleted the line

```
\frontmatter
```

now I have a decent format in the pdf file. I still have to understand why it works :-(